# How to manually set CPU clock frequency in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, clock, cpu-frequency

I have a first generation i7 computer and it is prone to overheating.  How can I set the CPU clock frequency in Fedora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command
`cpupower --cpu all frequency-info | grep "current CPU"`
to see what the frequency the cores are running at.

Use the command 
`cpupower --cpu all frequency-set --max 1.4GHz`
to set the CPU frequency to 1.4GHz

Comment: For those wondering: cpupower can be found in the kernel-tools package.